# rails 4 translate json in jbuilder template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, internationalization, jbuilder

I have a file called 'show.json.jbuilder' with the content:

```
json.extract! @person, :id, :first_name, :last_name, :title, :birthday, :gender, :created_at, :updated_at
```

In the view I can simply translate it using the i18n framework from rails, but this seems not to work in my jbuilder file.  Specially the :gender should be translated.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: How do you translate it soecifically?

Comment: in html.erb I do
    <%= t "activerecord.attributes.person.genders." + @person.gender %>

Comment: I put the translation in the model now, but I think this will not be the recommended way in RoR.

Answer (score 4):

Your `show.json.jbuilder` file is a view file – a view file that renders JSON rather than HTML. Which is good news! You've got access to the standard translation helpers. In this case, you'll want something like this:

```
json.id @person.id
json.first_name @person.first_name 
json.last_name @person.last_name
json.title @person.title
json.birthday @person.birthday
json.gender t(@person.gender) # Passing the gender field into the t() translation helper
json.created_at @person.created_at
json.updated_at @person.updated_at
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted to do, thanks very much